# John Bell's formulation of the Bell Inequality

Tags: bells-inequality

In "ON THE EINSTEIN-PODOLSKI-ROSEN PARADOX" by Bell(1964), Eq(14) says:
$$
\begin{align}
P(\vec{a},\vec{b})
&=\int{d\lambda\rho(\lambda)A(\vec{a},\lambda)B(\vec{b},\lambda)}\\
&=-\int{d\lambda\rho(\lambda)A(\vec{a},\lambda)A(\vec{b},\lambda)}
\end{align}
$$
Why is
$
B(\vec{b},\lambda)=-A(\vec{b},\lambda)
$
?

Comment: Try giving more context to the question and explaining your current thoughts on the matter that confuses you, so that people can answer to you accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember that part correctly: The assumption is that Alice always measures the opposite spin direction as Bob, whatever the situation might be.